# Conexión a Oracle desde C#

Tags: c#, oracle-11g

Tengo el la siguiente conexión pero puedo conectarme a la base de datos de Oracle:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=xe; USER ID=SYS; Password=Omar6180"/>
```

en el programa mando llamar a la conexión mediante el siguiente comando:

```
static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ToString();
```

Pero no me puedo conectar. Ayuda por favor! no encuentro algo similar en la red.

Comment: La pregunta no incluye suficiente detalles para poder ayudarte. ¿Recibes algún error? ¿Puedes compartir los detalles del error por favor?

Comment: Debes mostrar mas código, por ejemplo el codigo que usas para abrir la conexión. Lo único que nos muestras es como lees la cadena de conexión del app config.